# What do su - usrnm get?

Tags: security, opensuse, privacy

I will running some closed source programs in the current logging Konsole window by `su - usrnm` command, I know that'll share the desktop screen with the programs running under usrnm, not safe enough, and what other information will share to usrnm? like clipboard, etc...

Comment: I guess you should provide more details of this software.

Comment: I worry that may leak my privacy...it's a proxy software. Running other software with it's listening port.

Answer (score 1):

If your distribution arranges for X11 GUI access across `su - <username>` (i.e. you can successfully start new GUI programs as the `su`'d user), then the program has full access to your session on the X11 display server. That means:

- it can capture your keystrokes and mouse movements, even outside the program's *visible* windows if it wants to (it can open an invisible borderless full-screen window that passes all key/mouse events through to windows under it, and then snoop everything)
- it has access to the GUI session's clipboard
- if a program uses X11 properties to e.g. detect and communicate with other instances of itself, the closed source program can see and participate in that communication

Anything else depends on what X11 protocol extensions you're using, what desktop environment you're using, and other details.

If the closed-source program does not need a GUI, you can revoke its X11 access pretty easily, by doing these things after `su`'ing but before starting the closed-source program:

```
$ unset DISPLAY
$ unset XAUTHORITY
$ rm ~usrnm/.Xauthority
```

What remains is just a terminal session, similar to what you'd get by doing a

```
ssh -x -a usrnm@localhost
```

Comment: ouch! It,s serious about my security, is there any easy tools to tell me which files is accessed by which program running under user:usrnm?